# implementing push notifications for Cordova project with Firebase

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Cordova app and I'm trying to implement Push Notifications feature for it. My idea is to use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). I was able to implement it for a sample native Android application. How do I do it for this Cordova App?

Answer (score -1):

I am currently investigating [Firebase Cloud Messaging Cordova Push Plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) which looks promising.

In short:

> Extremely easy plug&play push notification plugin for Cordova applications and FCM.

It allow:

- Subscribe/unSubscribe to/from topic
- Receiving push notification data
- Send notification

Will update later my findings.